# Align element on the same level as v-card-title in vuetify

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

Is it possible to align element on the same height as the v-card-title in the card component of vuetify?
Currentl when using `class="float-right"` the element goes to the right but it is line below the title. I would like for it to be at the same level.
Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/ZEYZwRN):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
    width="400"
    >
<!--  Top row -->
    <v-card-title>Cafe Badilico</v-card-title>
      <button class="float-right">click me</button>
<!--     End of top row -->

<!-- Put components here -->
  
     
  
        
    <v-card-title >
     News 
    </v-card-title>
   
<v-list-item dense
        >
  
          <v-list-item-avatar>
             <v-avatar color="indigo" size="36">
      <span class="white--text headline">36</span>
    </v-avatar>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Header</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>Subheader</v-list-item-subtitle>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>2019-05-31</v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
   <v-divider></v-divider>
   <v-card-title >
     News 
   </v-card-title>
   
<v-list-item dense>
  
          <v-list-item-avatar>
             <v-avatar color="indigo" size="36">
      <span class="white--text headline">36</span>
    </v-avatar>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title ><a href="">Header</a></v-list-item-title>
           
            <v-list-item-subtitle >Subheader</v-list-item-subtitle>
            <v-list-item-subtitle >2019-05-31</v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      
  

    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: move button into `v-card-title` and add this class to it, `d-flex justify-space-between` , like this:
`<v-card-title class="d-flex justify-space-between">CARD TITLE<button>click me</button></v-card-title>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the button into the title and use the `v-spacer` component:

```
<v-card-title>
  Cafe Badilico
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <button>click me</button>
</v-card-title>
```

https://codepen.io/El_Matella/pen/mdJrKNE

If you don't want it to be part of the title component, you can also use a flex container:

```
<div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between">
  <v-card-title>
    Cafe Badilico
  </v-card-title>
  <button>click me</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/El_Matella/pen/ZEGpjEq